# How to select the current line inside ubuntu terminal with hotkeys and copy it inside main clipboard

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, shell

**How can i select the whole line in ubuntu terminal only with hotkeys?**

**CTRL+U** works, but puts it inside a buffer. How can i copy that buffer into the main clipboard?

Or how can i select/highlight the whole line and copy it with **CTRL + SHIFT + C**.

The only way i know at the moment is with mouse cursor, right click and copy. But i want to do it without mouse and add it into the main clipboard.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This depends on which terminal you are using. I don't think the standard terminal has easy keyboard shortcut access to individual elements of the scrollback buffer. I recall seeing offerings for MacOS which do; perhaps you can find one which works for Ubuntu, too. IIRC [Kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) might be worth a shot?